How do I split a value between two years over a date range in Excel?
This might be more simple than I'm making it, but I have yet to find or create a working function for this problem. I have data for upcoming projects that could begin and end anytime over the next two years, i.e. 2025 & 2026. I know the estimated start date for the project, the expected duration in weeks, and the estimated total cost of the projects.
I would like to split the cost of these projects relative to their duration between each year for budgeting purposes. Column A represents the project number, Column B represents the start month of the project, Column C represents its duration in weeks, Column D represents the end date, Column E represents the total cost, and Column F represents the weekly cost. I would like Column G to represent the portion of the cost of the project in 2025 and Column H to represent the portion of the cost of the project in 2026.
See Example
The example shows what I was given: project, start date, duration (in weeks), and total cost. Other calculations for project 2, for example: end date =B3+(C3*7). Weekly cost =E3/C3.
The next step - in my mind - would be (total weeks of project in 2025 * weekly cost) to calculate 2025 cost; 2026 cost = total cost - 2025 cost. I am unable to think of an equation/formula that will calculate or count the number of weeks in a date range that belong to a certain year.
The examples are easy enough to calculate manually, but with a larger data set and durations that are less divisible this becomes more difficult.
I unfortunately do not have a formula to show as an example as I'm not sure where to go from here, but I hope my explanation makes sense as to what I am looking for.
EDIT: Apologies everyone, I uploaded the incorrect date formats which resulted in wildly inaccurate examples of what I was looking for originally. The original image is edited to show what I meant to show last time.

What would you like to happen if there isn't an exact number of weeks covered in 2025 or 2026?

@TomSharpe I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Are you saying if the project might extend into 2027? Or if the project is not split into a round number of weeks? If you are referring to the latter, then I will just say that for my purposes estimates made by rounding to full weeks is more than sufficient. Also, these projects will not extend into 2027.

@Blackcat My apologies, projects 3 and 4 were calculated incorrectly as I had used the incorrect date format, see edit. And the 2025 cost calculations are made manually by counting the number of weeks the project has in 2025 and multiplying by the weekly cost, and the 2026 cost is the remainder. My problem was I needed a formula to solve these calculations rather than manual entry for use in more complex entries and larger data sets.

I can propose you this formula:

[G2]=MIN([@[duration (weeks)]]*7,MAX(0,DATE(2026,1,1)-[@[start date]]))/7*[@[weekly cost]]


Assuming that the third and fourth rows in your sample are incorrect, this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac).
Please note that the algorithm that should be used depends on whether the both start and end dates are included in the project days. We may need to tweak the algorithm a bit depending on that
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

Note that the algorithm can deal with projects that last any number of years.
Original Data

M-Code
let

//change next line to reflect actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Projects"]}[Content],

//set the data types for each column
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"project", Int64.Type}, {"start date", type date}, {"duration (weeks)", Int64.Type}, 
        {"total cost", Currency.Type}}),

//calculate the end date
    #"Add End Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","end date", each Date.AddDays([start date], [#"duration (weeks)"]*7), type date),

    #"Yearly Costs" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add End Date","Daily Cost", 
    (r)=> 
        let  
        
         //use daily costs since a year will include a fraction of a week
            #"Daily Costs" = r[total cost]/r[#"duration (weeks)"]/7,

        //create list of all the years in the project
            yrs = {Date.Year(r[start date])..Date.Year(r[end date])},

        //calculate number of days in each year for the project
            #"Days in Years" = List.Generate(
                ()=>[dys=Duration.Days(List.Min({Date.EndOfYear(r[start date]), r[end date]}) - r[start date]),idx=0],
                each [idx]< List.Count(yrs),
                each [dys = Duration.Days(List.Min({#date(yrs{[idx]+1},12,31),r[end date]}) - #date(yrs{[idx]+1},1,1))+1, idx=[idx]+1],
                each [dys]),

        //cost per year = cost per day X number of days in each year
            #"Cost per Year" = List.Transform(#"Days in Years", each _ * #"Daily Costs"),

        //create output as records
            records = Record.FromList(#"Cost per Year", List.Transform(yrs, each Text.From(_)))
        in 
           records, type record),

//create list of column names for record expansion and setting data types
    colNames = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(#"Yearly Costs"[Daily Cost], each Record.FieldNames(_)))),

//create transforms list for data types
    colTypes = List.Transform(colNames, each {_, Currency.Type}),

//expand the data column and set the data types
    #"Expanded Daily Cost" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Yearly Costs", "Daily Cost", colNames),
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Daily Cost", colTypes)
in
    Typed

Results from above data

Note that this algorithm shows the same results as you show for rows one and two.
If we are including both the start and end dates as project dates, then the following may be more appropriate
let

//change next line to reflect actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Projects"]}[Content],

//set the data types for each column
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"project", Int64.Type}, {"start date", type date}, {"duration (weeks)", Int64.Type}, 
        {"total cost", Currency.Type}}),

//calculate the end date
    #"Add End Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","end date", each Date.AddDays([start date], [#"duration (weeks)"]*7), type date),

    #"Yearly Costs" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add End Date","Daily Cost", 
    (r)=> 
        let  
        
         //use daily costs since a year will include a fraction of a week
            #"Daily Costs" = r[total cost]/(1+Duration.Days(r[end date]-r[start date])),

        //create list of all the years in the project
            yrs = {Date.Year(r[start date])..Date.Year(r[end date])},

        //calculate number of days in each year for the project
            #"Days in Years" = List.Generate(
                ()=>[dys=1+Duration.Days(List.Min({Date.EndOfYear(r[start date]), r[end date]}) - r[start date]),idx=0],
                each [idx]< List.Count(yrs),
                each [dys = 1+Duration.Days(List.Min({#date(yrs{[idx]+1},12,31),r[end date]}) - #date(yrs{[idx]+1},1,1)), idx=[idx]+1],
                each [dys]),

        //cost per year = cost per day X number of days in each year
            #"Cost per Year" = List.Transform(#"Days in Years", each _ * #"Daily Costs"),

        //create output as records
            records = Record.FromList(#"Cost per Year", List.Transform(yrs, each Text.From(_)))
        in 
           records, type record),

//create list of column names for record expansion and setting data types
    colNames = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(#"Yearly Costs"[Daily Cost], each Record.FieldNames(_)))),

//create transforms list for data types
    colTypes = List.Transform(colNames, each {_, Currency.Type}),

//expand the data column and set the data types
    #"Expanded Daily Cost" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Yearly Costs", "Daily Cost", colNames),
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Daily Cost", colTypes)
in
    Typed

Results Inclusive


Thank you for the solution, Ron! I apologize, I was using the incorrect date format and hadn't even noticed previously, see my edit. This solution is very helpful in following step-by-step and allowing me to see the logical process and code.

@ReignofError I'm glad the code gave you some insight. And the date format would only change the output values. And if you want to attribute to 2025 only those weeks that start in 2025, again the algorithm would need some tweaking.

@ReignofError I can provide that code (which replicates what you show for output) if you prefer that result to the formula result above.
